# tested keys inside JavaScript object for API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get a json object returned from this function here's the code this runs and logs for example "firstname john" which is what i am expecting.

```
var req = { 'body' : {
    'firstname':'john',
    'middlename':'matrix',
    'lastname':'smith',
    'test' :'jesus'}
    };

var targets = ['firstname' , 'middlename', 'lastname'];

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(req.body).length; i++) {
    if(targets.includes(Object.keys(req.body)[i])){
        console.log(Object.keys(req.body)[i], req.body[Object.keys(req.body)[i]]);
    }
}
```

if i make the console.log() log an object instead of a string for example:

```
console.log({Object.keys(req.body)[i] : req.body[Object.keys(req.body)[i]]});
```

it throws a syntax error, is there a better way to do this/how can i get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to stick with the `Object.keys` approach, you should call it once and capture the value so that your code is more efficient and easier to read:

```
var keys = Object.keys(req.body);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if(targets.includes(keys[i])){
        console.log(keys[i], req.body[keys[i]]);
    }
}
```

You could simplify quite a bit by working with the object instead of an array

```js
var req = { 'body' : {
    'firstname':'john',
    'middlename':'matrix',
    'lastname':'smith',
    'test' :'jesus'}
    };

var targets = ['firstname' , 'middlename', 'lastname'];

for (var prop in req.body) {
   if (targets.includes(prop)) {
      console.log(`${prop}: ${req.body[prop]}`)
      // as an object
      console.log({ [prop]: req.body[prop] })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for` function for objects, the first parameter referring to the keys, and second one to the whole object

```
var req = { 'body' : {
    'firstname':'john',
    'middlename':'matrix',
    'lastname':'smith',
    'test' :'jesus'}
    };

var targets = ['firstname' , 'middlename', 'lastname'];

for(var key in req['body']){
    console.log('the key is '+ key + ' the value is ' + req['body'][key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to set a dynamic key in an object, you have to use brackets, like this:

```
const obj = {
  [keyName]: null,
};
```

So, in your example, you have to fix the syntax error like this:

```
console.log({
  [Object.keys(req.body)[i]]: req.body[Object.keys(req.body)[i]]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The below builds an object `foo` by iterating through the `targets` array and searching for the properties it cares about in `req.body` using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(key)`, which should be an O(1) check, then prints `foo`:

```
var req = { 'body' : {
    'firstname':'john',
    'middlename':'matrix',
    'lastname':'smith',
    'test' :'jesus'}
    };

var targets = ['firstname' , 'middlename', 'lastname'];

let foo = {};
for (let key of targets) {
  if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(key))
    foo[key] = req.body[key];
}

console.log(foo);
```

Also, if you decide to introspect an Object's properties, you can use for..in looping. For iterating over Arrays, you can use for..of.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: I found the links to the docs super helpful cleared up a few other questions i had, could you explain what you mean by O(1) check? never heard that phrase before thank you in advance!

Comment: Sure, O(1) refers to the time complexity of the operation being constant time. To oversimplify things, I generally mean that it's faster to search through an Object for a specific key/property since it's a mapping structure, as opposed to searching for a specific element in an array. That's mostly the reason why I reversed the roles of which data structure to search through when looking for `key`. And by that, I mean instead of Array.prototype.includes(), use Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty().

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/asymptotic_analysis.htm